# pythonからmysqlに接続すると日本語が文字化けする

Tags: python, mysql, docker

dockerを用いてpythonとmysqlのコンテナをそれぞれ作成し、pythonからmysqlに接続しfetchallでテーブルを表示しようとすると日本語が文字化けしました。

MySQLイメージ: mysql:5.7
Pythonイメージ: 3.7
mysql-connector-python: 8.0.31
サーバーとクライアントのIP: 異なる

[docker-compose_yml]

```
version: '3'

services:
  # MySQL
  db:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./db/Dockerfile
    container_name: mysql_host
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: pass
      MYSQL_DATABASE: test_database
      MYSQL_USER: user
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: pass
      TZ: 'Asia/Tokyo'
    volumes:
    - ./db/data:/var/lib/mysql
    - ./log/mysql:/var/log/mysql
    - ./db/my.cnf:/etc/mysql/conf.d/my.cnf
    ports:
    - 3306:3306
    ## For static IP address
    networks:
      python_network:
        ipv4_address: 192.168.2.2              

## python3 
  python3:
    restart: always
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./python/Dockerfile
    container_name: "python3"
    working_dir: "/root/src"
    tty: true
    volumes:
      - ./python:/root/src
    links:
      - db 
    networks:
      - python_network

networks: 
  python_network:
    driver: bridge
    ipam:
      driver: default
      config:
       - subnet: 192.168.2.0/24
         gateway: 192.168.2.1
```

[/db/Dockerfile]

```
FROM mysql:5.7
ADD  ./db/my.cnf /etc/mysql/conf.d/my.cnf
RUN chmod 644 /etc/mysql/conf.d/my.cnf
```

[/python/Dockerfile]

```
FROM python:3.7

RUN pip install --upgrade pip
RUN pip install --upgrade setuptools
RUN pip install mysql-connector-python
```

[my.cnf](latin1;utf8mb4,utf8でそれぞれ試した。

```
[mysqld]
# 文字コード、整合順序の設定
character-set-server=utf8mb4
collation-server=utf8mb4_unicode_ci
secure-file-priv=""

[mysql]
default-character-set=utf8mb4

[client]
default-character-set=utf8mb4
user = user
password = pass
```

mysqlコンテナに入り直接表示してみた所、文字コードの設定により文字化けしたりしなかったりします。

```
select * from sample;
```

**文字化けする場合:**

```
+--------------------------+----------------------------+
| Variable_name            | Value                      |
+--------------------------+----------------------------+
| character_set_client     | utf8mb4                    |
| character_set_connection | utf8mb4                    |
| character_set_database   | utf8mb4                    |
| character_set_filesystem | binary                     |
| character_set_results    | utf8mb4                    |
| character_set_server     | utf8mb4                    |
| character_set_system     | utf8                       |
| character_sets_dir       | /usr/share/mysql/charsets/ |
+--------------------------+----------------------------+
```

**文字化けしない場合:**

```
+--------------------------+----------------------------+
| Variable_name            | Value                      |
+--------------------------+----------------------------+
| character_set_client     | latin1                     |
| character_set_connection | utf8mb4                    |
| character_set_database   | utf8mb4                    |
| character_set_filesystem | binary                     |
| character_set_results    | latin1                     |
| character_set_server     | utf8mb4                    |
| character_set_system     | utf8                       |
| character_sets_dir       | /usr/share/mysql/charsets/ |
+--------------------------+----------------------------+
```

扱うデータの都合上、latin1で取得すると正しく表示されるようです。
また、メモ帳(utf8)でレコードを開くと文字化けしていました。

そこでpythonのコードから文字コードを変更し、設定を表示しつつ再度試した所、

```
('character_set_client', 'latin1')
('character_set_connection', 'utf8mb4')
('character_set_database', 'utf8mb4')
('character_set_filesystem', 'binary')
('character_set_results', 'latin1')
('character_set_server', 'utf8mb4')
('character_set_system', 'utf8')
('character_sets_dir', '/usr/share/mysql/charsets/')
```

と文字コードの設定は同じなのにpythonから読むと文字化けしてしまいした。charsetや文字コードの変更（全てutf8mb4またはutf8にする等）、色々試しましたが文字化けします。

```
# coding: latin1
import mysql.connector

#pythonからmysqlに接続
cnx = mysql.connector.connect(
host='',
port='3306',
user='user',
password='pass',
database='test_database',
charset='latin1'
    )
cursor_=cnx.cursor()

cursor_.execute("use test_database;")

#文字コードを変更し設定の状況を取得
query1 = "SET CHARACTER SET latin1;"
cursor_.execute(query1)

cursor_.execute("show variables like 'chara%';")
rows = cursor_.fetchall()
for row in rows:
  print (row)

cursor_.execute("select * from test;")
rows = cursor_.fetchall()
for row in rows:
  print (row)
```

また、printにcordingを付ける試みはtuple型であった為に失敗しました。これの解決法も不明です。

```
for row in rows:
  print (row.cording(utf8やlatin1))
```

```
'tuple' object has no attribute 'encord'
```

どなたかlatin1で取得したデータをpythonから表示する方法をご存知ないでしょうか

Comment: 検索して見つかるこの辺の記事がそのままでは無いにしろ参考になるかもしれません。[PythonのMySQLdbでUTF-8の日本語文字を扱う。](https://qiita.com/apopon/items/f81e865b0b173db73456), [Unknown charset: utf8mb4](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/314755/unknown-charset-utf8mb4), [Djangoでのmysql設定。ついでに絵文字対策 utf8mb4](https://boook24.com/?p=999), [MySQLのテーブル作成後に、文字コードをutf8mb4に変更する](https://www.karakaram.com/changing-the-character-set-to-utf8mb4-after-creating-mysql-table/)

Comment: ちなみに`cnx = mysql.connector.connect(...)`で明示的に`charset='latin1'`を指定しているからでは？ こちら [7.1 Connector/Python Connection Arguments](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-connectargs.html) では`charsetは`デフォルトで`utf8mb4`になっていますが。

Comment: MySQLイメージのタグを正確に記述しましょう。コマンドについても正確に記載し、pythonの環境についても正確に記述しましょう。pipでインストールしたものがあれば、それも正確に記述しましょう。他の人が同じ状態を再現できることが「最低限」必要です。

Comment: 説明不足の件、大変失礼いたしました。分かる範囲で情報を追記しました。
charsetはuft8mb4,latin1どちらでも文字化けしました。

Comment: こんな記事があるようですが。[MySQL(InnoDB) で charset を utf8mb4 にする注意点の現在](https://dev.to/seizans/mysqlinnodb--charset--utf8mb4--1451), [MySQLのencodingをutf8からutf8mb4に変更して寿司ビール問題に対応する](https://techracho.bpsinc.jp/hachi8833/2020_11_26/25044)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## 回答ではありません

質問が全く正確でないため、また原因が不明なため、回答にはなっていません。

### 前提

質問が以下のコードで構築される環境だと仮定します。

MySQLイメージ: mysql:8.0.31
Python: 3.10.9
mysql-connector-python: 8.0.31
PyMySQL:                1.0.2
サーバーとクライアントのIP: 異なる

#### コード

※空のディレクトリで実行すること
**create_env.sh**

```bash
WAIT_SETUP_MYSQL=10
cat >my.cnf <<EOF
[mysqld]
character-set-server = utf8mb4
collation-server = utf8mb4_unicode_ci
#[client]
#default-character-set=utf8mb4
EOF
cat >docker-compose.yml <<EOF
version: '3.1'
services:
  db:
    image: mysql:8
    command: --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password 
    volumes:
      - ./data:/var/lib/mysql
      - ./logs:/var/log/mysql
      - ./my.cnf:/etc/mysql/conf.d/my.cnf
    ports:
      - 3306:3306
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: example
      TZ: 'Asia/Tokyo'
  python:
    image: python:3.10
    volumes:
      - ./python/:/opt/project/
EOF
docker-compose up -d db
docker-compose exec -T db bash <<EOF
while sleep 1;do if [ -S /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock ];then break;fi;done
sleep $WAIT_SETUP_MYSQL
EOF
docker-compose exec -T db bash <<EOF
mysql --user=root --password=example
use mysql
create user \`user\`@\`%\` IDENTIFIED BY 'python';
create database sampledb character set utf8mb4 collate utf8mb4_bin;
grant all on sampledb.* to user;
use sampledb
create table sample(
id varchar(20) primary key,
name varchar(1024)
);
insert into sample values('1001', 'dockerを用いてpythonからmysqlに接続すると日本語が文字化けする');
insert into sample values('1002', 'dockerを用いてpythonとmysqlのコンテナをそれぞれ作成し');
insert into sample values('1003', 'pythonからmysqlに接続しfetchallでテーブルを表示しようとすると');
insert into sample values('1004', '             ');
exit
EOF
docker-compose exec -T db bash <<EOF
mysql --user=user --password=python --database=sampledb
show variables like 'chara%';
select * from sample;
exit
EOF
docker-compose exec -T db bash <<EOF
mysql --user=user --password=python --database=sampledb --default-character-set=utf8mb4
show variables like 'chara%';
select * from sample;
exit
EOF
docker-compose run --rm python bash <<EOF
cd /opt/project
python -m venv env
./env/bin/python -m pip install mysql-connector-python PyMySQL
cat >sample.py <<INNER_EOF
import mysql.connector
cnx = mysql.connector.connect(
    host='db',
    port='3306',
    user='user',
    password='python',
    database='sampledb',
    charset='utf8mb4'
)
cursor_=cnx.cursor()
cursor_.execute("show variables like 'chara%';")
rows = cursor_.fetchall()
for row in rows:
    print (row)
cursor_.execute("select * from sample;")
rows = cursor_.fetchall()
for row in rows:
    print (row)
INNER_EOF
cat >sample2.py <<INNER_EOF
import pymysql.cursors
cnx = pymysql.connect(
    host='db',
    port=3306,
    user='user',
    password='python',
    database='sampledb',
    charset='utf8mb4'
)
cursor_=cnx.cursor()
cursor_.execute("show variables like 'chara%';")
rows = cursor_.fetchall()
for row in rows:
    print (row)
cursor_.execute("select * from sample;")
rows = cursor_.fetchall()
for row in rows:
    print (row)
INNER_EOF
./env/bin/python sample.py
./env/bin/python sample2.py
EOF
docker-compose down
```

#### 出力

```
$ sh ../create_env.sh 
Creating network "tmp_default" with the default driver
Creating tmp_db_1 ... done
mysql: [Warning] Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure.
ERROR 1396 (HY000) at line 2: Operation CREATE USER failed for 'user'@'%'
mysql: [Warning] Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure.
Variable_name   Value
character_set_client    latin1
character_set_connection        latin1
character_set_database  utf8mb4
character_set_filesystem        binary
character_set_results   latin1
character_set_server    utf8mb4
character_set_system    utf8mb3
character_sets_dir      /usr/share/mysql-8.0/charsets/
id      name
1001    dockerを用いてpythonからmysqlに接続すると日本語が文字化けする
1002    dockerを用いてpythonとmysqlのコンテナをそれぞれ作成し
1003    pythonからmysqlに接続しfetchallでテーブルを表示しようとすると
1004                 
mysql: [Warning] Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure.
Variable_name   Value
character_set_client    utf8mb4
character_set_connection        utf8mb4
character_set_database  utf8mb4
character_set_filesystem        binary
character_set_results   utf8mb4
character_set_server    utf8mb4
character_set_system    utf8mb3
character_sets_dir      /usr/share/mysql-8.0/charsets/
id      name
1001    dockerã‚’ç”¨ã„ã¦pythonã‹ã‚‰mysqlã«æŽ¥ç¶šã™ã‚‹ã¨æ—¥æœ¬èªžãŒæ–‡å­—åŒ–ã‘ã™ã‚‹
1002    dockerã‚’ç”¨ã„ã¦pythonã¨mysqlã®ã‚³ãƒ³ãƒ†ãƒŠã‚’ãã‚Œãžã‚Œä½œæˆã—
1003    pythonã‹ã‚‰mysqlã«æŽ¥ç¶šã—fetchallã§ãƒ†ãƒ¼ãƒ–ãƒ«ã‚’è¡¨ç¤ºã—ã‚ˆã†ã¨ã™ã‚‹ã¨
1004    ðŸ¤§ ðŸ˜· ðŸ¤’ ðŸ¤• ðŸ¤‘ ðŸ¤  ðŸ˜ˆ ðŸ‘¿ ðŸ‘¹ ðŸ‘º ðŸ¤¡ ðŸ’© ðŸ‘» ðŸ’€
Requirement already satisfied: mysql-connector-python in ./env/lib/python3.10/site-packages (8.0.31)
Requirement already satisfied: PyMySQL in ./env/lib/python3.10/site-packages (1.0.2)
Requirement already satisfied: protobuf<=3.20.1,>=3.11.0 in ./env/lib/python3.10/site-packages (from mysql-connector-python) (3.20.1)
('character_set_client', 'utf8mb4')
('character_set_connection', 'utf8mb4')
('character_set_database', 'utf8mb4')
('character_set_filesystem', 'binary')
('character_set_results', 'utf8mb4')
('character_set_server', 'utf8mb4')
('character_set_system', 'utf8mb3')
('character_sets_dir', '/usr/share/mysql-8.0/charsets/')
('1001', 'dockerã‚’ç”¨ã\x81„ã\x81¦pythonã\x81‹ã‚‰mysqlã\x81«æŽ¥ç¶šã\x81™ã‚‹ã\x81¨æ—¥æœ¬èªžã\x81Œæ–‡å\xad—åŒ–ã\x81‘ã\x81™ã‚‹')
('1002', 'dockerã‚’ç”¨ã\x81„ã\x81¦pythonã\x81¨mysqlã\x81®ã‚³ãƒ³ãƒ†ãƒŠã‚’ã\x81\x9dã‚Œã\x81žã‚Œä½œæˆ\x90ã\x81—')
('1003', 'pythonã\x81‹ã‚‰mysqlã\x81«æŽ¥ç¶šã\x81—fetchallã\x81§ãƒ†ãƒ¼ãƒ–ãƒ«ã‚’è¡¨ç¤ºã\x81—ã‚ˆã\x81†ã\x81¨ã\x81™ã‚‹ã\x81¨')
('1004', 'ðŸ¤§ ðŸ˜· ðŸ¤’ ðŸ¤• ðŸ¤‘ ðŸ¤\xa0 ðŸ˜ˆ ðŸ‘¿ ðŸ‘¹ ðŸ‘º ðŸ¤¡ ðŸ’© ðŸ‘» ðŸ’€')
('character_set_client', 'utf8mb4')
('character_set_connection', 'utf8mb4')
('character_set_database', 'utf8mb4')
('character_set_filesystem', 'binary')
('character_set_results', 'utf8mb4')
('character_set_server', 'utf8mb4')
('character_set_system', 'utf8mb3')
('character_sets_dir', '/usr/share/mysql-8.0/charsets/')
('1001', 'dockerã‚’ç”¨ã\x81„ã\x81¦pythonã\x81‹ã‚‰mysqlã\x81«æŽ¥ç¶šã\x81™ã‚‹ã\x81¨æ—¥æœ¬èªžã\x81Œæ–‡å\xad—åŒ–ã\x81‘ã\x81™ã‚‹')
('1002', 'dockerã‚’ç”¨ã\x81„ã\x81¦pythonã\x81¨mysqlã\x81®ã‚³ãƒ³ãƒ†ãƒŠã‚’ã\x81\x9dã‚Œã\x81žã‚Œä½œæˆ\x90ã\x81—')
('1003', 'pythonã\x81‹ã‚‰mysqlã\x81«æŽ¥ç¶šã\x81—fetchallã\x81§ãƒ†ãƒ¼ãƒ–ãƒ«ã‚’è¡¨ç¤ºã\x81—ã‚ˆã\x81†ã\x81¨ã\x81™ã‚‹ã\x81¨')
('1004', 'ðŸ¤§ ðŸ˜· ðŸ¤’ ðŸ¤• ðŸ¤‘ ðŸ¤\xa0 ðŸ˜ˆ ðŸ‘¿ ðŸ‘¹ ðŸ‘º ðŸ¤¡ ðŸ’© ðŸ‘» ðŸ’€')
Stopping tmp_db_1 ... done
Removing tmp_db_1 ... done
Removing network tmp_default
$
```

### 原因

不明。
`character_set_system`がクライアント側の`default_character_set`と異なるためなのか、なぜかlatin1で処理された。

### 対策

my.cnfのコメントを外す

#### 出力

```
$ sh ../create_env.sh 
Creating network "tmp_default" with the default driver
Creating tmp_db_1 ... done
mysql: [Warning] Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure.
mysql: [Warning] Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure.
Variable_name   Value
character_set_client    utf8mb4
character_set_connection        utf8mb4
character_set_database  utf8mb4
character_set_filesystem        binary
character_set_results   utf8mb4
character_set_server    utf8mb4
character_set_system    utf8mb3
character_sets_dir      /usr/share/mysql-8.0/charsets/
id      name
1001    dockerを用いてpythonからmysqlに接続すると日本語が文字化けする
1002    dockerを用いてpythonとmysqlのコンテナをそれぞれ作成し
1003    pythonからmysqlに接続しfetchallでテーブルを表示しようとすると
1004                 
mysql: [Warning] Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure.
Variable_name   Value
character_set_client    utf8mb4
character_set_connection        utf8mb4
character_set_database  utf8mb4
character_set_filesystem        binary
character_set_results   utf8mb4
character_set_server    utf8mb4
character_set_system    utf8mb3
character_sets_dir      /usr/share/mysql-8.0/charsets/
id      name
1001    dockerを用いてpythonからmysqlに接続すると日本語が文字化けする
1002    dockerを用いてpythonとmysqlのコンテナをそれぞれ作成し
1003    pythonからmysqlに接続しfetchallでテーブルを表示しようとすると
1004                 
Collecting mysql-connector-python
  Downloading mysql_connector_python-8.0.31-cp310-cp310-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (23.5 MB)
     ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 23.5/23.5 MB 27.1 MB/s eta 0:00:00
Collecting PyMySQL
  Downloading PyMySQL-1.0.2-py3-none-any.whl (43 kB)
     ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 43.8/43.8 kB 5.7 MB/s eta 0:00:00
Collecting protobuf<=3.20.1,>=3.11.0
  Downloading protobuf-3.20.1-cp310-cp310-manylinux_2_12_x86_64.manylinux2010_x86_64.whl (1.1 MB)
     ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 1.1/1.1 MB 12.6 MB/s eta 0:00:00
Installing collected packages: PyMySQL, protobuf, mysql-connector-python
Successfully installed PyMySQL-1.0.2 mysql-connector-python-8.0.31 protobuf-3.20.1
('character_set_client', 'utf8mb4')
('character_set_connection', 'utf8mb4')
('character_set_database', 'utf8mb4')
('character_set_filesystem', 'binary')
('character_set_results', 'utf8mb4')
('character_set_server', 'utf8mb4')
('character_set_system', 'utf8mb3')
('character_sets_dir', '/usr/share/mysql-8.0/charsets/')
('1001', 'dockerを用いてpythonからmysqlに接続すると日本語が文字化けする')
('1002', 'dockerを用いてpythonとmysqlのコンテナをそれぞれ作成し')
('1003', 'pythonからmysqlに接続しfetchallでテーブルを表示しようとすると')
('1004', '             ')
('character_set_client', 'utf8mb4')
('character_set_connection', 'utf8mb4')
('character_set_database', 'utf8mb4')
('character_set_filesystem', 'binary')
('character_set_results', 'utf8mb4')
('character_set_server', 'utf8mb4')
('character_set_system', 'utf8mb3')
('character_sets_dir', '/usr/share/mysql-8.0/charsets/')
('1001', 'dockerを用いてpythonからmysqlに接続すると日本語が文字化けする')
('1002', 'dockerを用いてpythonとmysqlのコンテナをそれぞれ作成し')
('1003', 'pythonからmysqlに接続しfetchallでテーブルを表示しようとすると')
('1004', '             ')
Stopping tmp_db_1 ... done
Removing tmp_db_1 ... done
Removing network tmp_default
$
```

Comment: 不正確な質問をお詫びします。詳細な事例を頂きありがとうございます。
この事例を再現できたのですが、手元のレコードを入れてみるとやはり文字化けするようです。レコードがutf8で読めるものでない事が原因かと思います（メモ帳で開いても文字化けしている）。

Comment: いえいえ、伝わればいいだけで責めるつもりはありません。こちらこそ原因自体が不明なまま書いちゃってすみません。頑張ってください。